# Oracle to Snowflake replication. How to handle tables loaded using EXCHANGE PARTITION

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, oracle-golden-gate

We are replicating Oracle to Snowflake and have cases where Oracle tables are loaded using EXCHANGE PARTITION.

GoldenGate doesn't support DDL for Snowflake as a target, and additionally Snowflake doesn't support EXCHANGE PARTITION.

I was wondering if there might be a way to get around this. For example, replicating the initial table from Oracle to Snowflake, and then capturing the ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION ddl command but map it to a stored procedure on Snowflake which performs an ALTER TABLE SWAP WITH command instead?

Comment: May be you can use this workaround - store the data in stage table ( temp table). Then drop the partition data from main table and insert into the main table.

Comment: Ideally we don't want to be refactoring ETL jobs in order to achieve this. Using partition exchange makes this a very fast operation and seamless as far as end users are concerned. In order to make that suggestion seamless, we'd need to do a delete first and then an insert, which could be very time consuming considering the size of some of our tables. A truncate would result in queries against an empty table.

Comment: You can use clustering and mention the partition key as cluster key. This will make your deletion operation faster.